# Passing the name for a new object as parameter

Tags: c++

I try to program a universal state machine which should get all relevant information in the constructor. E.g. in the form below:

```
StateMachine stateMachine =
{
    {"state1", 1.5f, 4, 'c'},
    {"state2", 5.3f, 2, 'z'}
};
```

The contructor of StateMachine takes an initializer_list. Param is a struct which holds all information.

```
//constructor
StateMachine(std::initializer_list<param> il) 
{
    test = new param[il.size()];
    for (size_t i = 0; i < il.size(); i++)
        test[i] = *(il.begin() + i);
}
```

And the struct looks like this:

```
struct param
{
    float f;
    int i;
    char c;
    PassTest *test = nullptr;

    param() 
    {
        std::cout << "WHY" << std::endl;
    }

    param(std::string pass, float f, int i, char c) : test(new PassTest(pass)), f(f), i(i), c(c)
    {
        std::cout << f << '\t' << i << '\t' << c << std::endl;
    }
};
```

So far I can store the information `{"state1", 1.5f, 4, 'c'}` in one object of param. But I would like to replace the string "state1" with a name for a param object so I can access this object directly with the name defined in the StateMachine constructor.
To get you an impression of how it should look like.

```
StateMachine stateMachine =
{
    {State1, 1.5f, 4, 'c'}, //State1 and State2 is no longer a String
    {State2, 5.3f, 2, 'z'}
};
```

Do you have any idea how to do that?

PS. This is a test setup without templates or other dynamic elements. These will be added later.

Comment: What is the question? SO is about specific programming Q&A, not code review. Please take [the tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and read [the help page](https://stackoverflow.com/help). Welcome to SO.

Comment: `StateMachine::test` should very likely be a `std::vector<param>`, not a pointer.

Comment: If `State1` to `StateN` are all known at compile time, then I'd just use an `enum` (or rather, a type-safe `enum class`) for them.

Answer (score 0):

This question is pretty unclear for me...
But if I understand your problem correctly:
In `StateMachine` constuctor, just pass an usual array or an vector of `param`
(`std::vector<param>`, http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/vector/vector/)

```
std::vector<param> prlist;
prlist.push_back(param("State1", 1.5f, 4, 'c'));
prlist.push_back(param("State2", 5.3f, 2, 'z'));
StateMachine machine = StateMachine(prlist);
```

Then you also need to modify the `StateMachine` class constructor:

```
//constructor
StateMachine(std::vector<param> il) 
{
    test = new param[il.size()];
    for (size_t i = 0; i < il.size(); i++)
        test[i] = il[i];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

So you want to pass a "future" variable name to a function and have the function define the variable for you? Sorry, this is not possible in C++. The closest you can get are macros. For example:

```
#define ADD_NAMED_ENTRY(name,value) \
  int name = (value); \
  entries.push_back(name);

int main() {
  std::vector<int> entries;
  ADD_NAMED_ENTRY(first, 1);
  ADD_NAMED_ENTRY(second, 42);
  // now the vector contains {1,42} but variables first and second also exist and have values 1 and 42, respectively
}
```

Note, however, that you couldn't pass a brace initializer for `value` (because the preprocessor does not understand its `{..., ..., ...}` format and would break on the comma). You'd need to unfold that to something like `ADD_NAMED_ENTRY(State1, 1.5f, 4, 'c');`.

In your situation I would rather suggest having `StateMachine` keep an `std::unordered_map` indexed by the state names instead of integers: this way you could use your original code and refer to the states (defined using strings) along the lines of `states["state1"]`, rather than polluting the namescope by new symbols and having to cope with their visibility, lifetime etc.

Comment: Your macro is disguised as a function. If there's one thing worse than using macros, it's not using `ALL_CAPS` for them.

Comment: @ChristianHackl Fixed.